# Can someone help me adapt this regex / Textile Live Preview?

Tags: jquery, regex, textile

I have these lines of code in a jquery textile parser:

```
 re = new RegExp('"\\b(.+?)\\(\\b(.+?)\\b\\)":([^\\s]+)','g');
 r = r.replace(re,'<a href="$3" title="$2">$1</a>');

 re = new RegExp('"\\b(.+?)\\b":([^\\s]+)','g');
 r = r.replace(re,'<a href="$2">$1</a>');
```

These lines of code search for strings like

```
 "hello this is an embedded link":http://www.google.com
```

And replace them with

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">hello this is an embedded link</a>
```

However, the parser is unable to recognize strings with a period preceding the closing quotation marks:

```
 "This is also a link.":http://www.google.com
```

How can I change the regex on these lines to allow periods to precede the end quote? I can post more information and lines if it will help. I just have no idea how to write regexes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the

```
re = new RegExp('"\\b(.+?)\\b":([^\\s]+)','g');
```

to

```
re = /"(?!\s)([^"]*\S)":(\S+)/g;
```

should fix that.

Same changes could be applied to the first expression, like:

```
re = /"(?!\s)([^"()]+)\(([^"()]+)\)":(\S+)/g;
```